# 301 редирект дублей на основную страницу через .htaccess

Tags: редирект, mod_rewrite, .htaccess

Суть вопроса: Вордпресс генерирует дубли страниц в большом количестве вида http://site.ru/post/68765468765/ (в конце произвольные цифры), в индексе уже тысяча страниц и руками это убиться исправлять.
нужен автоматический 301 редирект таких страниц  на основную страницу http://site.ru/post/
Есть нюанс: на сайте присутствуют страницы третьего уровня *только* для новостей и имеют вид http://site.ru/news/post/

Answer (score 1):

Вот правила для автоматического редиректа:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/post/\d+/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /post/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Постов то много, на каждый такое писать?

Comment: @donkey, хамить вовсе не обязательно.  

Исходя из текста вопроса нельзя однозначно сказать, наблюдается ли данная проблема для всех страниц второго уровня или только принадлежащих разделу **post**. Кроме того, **явно** не указано, что нужно удалить дубли **для всех** страниц второго уровня.  
Чтобы не делать лишнюю работу и не навредить я решил ответить точно на вопрос автора не придумывая лишнего.

Answer (score 0):

```
RedirectMatch /(.*)[0-9]+/ http://example.com/$1
```

Так например можно отрезать цифры в конце урла